# Filtering popular items by using day / week / month

Tags: php, mysql, filtering

I am developing a website which will have 200.000 pages. There is also a browse section, which shows most popular, highest rated etc. documents. However this section will become almost static couple of weeks later, after launch. So I also would like to implement a filtering system which will show today's, this week's, this month's most popular items, just like youtube.

Just like this:

http://www.youtube.com/videos?c=2

How should I implement this function? Do I need another table, which will have a new entry for every document each day?

docid, date, view_count, rating

So I will get today's row for filtering by using a day, or calculate a week (7 rows) for filtering by using week? It seems not efficient. Do you have any suggestions?

I am using LAMP stack by the way.

Thanks,

Comment: keep in mind security concerns, if you don't want a single user to be able to, for example, generate 1000 views per second. Good luck implementing a way to stop a determined attacker though..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you timestamp the records in your table, you should be able to put a where clause that limits the timestamp to whatever timeframe you want.

You can cache the result, especially the longer ones, for long enough to make the request inconsequential.

EDIT

But perhaps you mean most popular today, not most popular that was added today?

In which case, I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct approach is to save the timestamp and the resource id each time the resource is shown in `recent_views(what, when)`. Daily/weekly/monthly charts can be created with appropriate WHERE clauses like `WHERE when > $beginOfPeriod AND when < $endOfPeriod`.

For performance reasons you can aggregate the values each night, save the sums in separate tables like `daily_views(what, sum)` and truncate the source table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would calculate the date's in code and then pass them as arguments, to the SQL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a compiler. Youtube probably does that too, considering the amount of traffic and the response times.

The principle is easy to understand. You log every every view or rating in a `page_view` table. You define periods at which the compilation occurs (hourly, daily, weekly, monthly). Every time you hit the good time (e.g.: end of the day), you execute the compiler, which essentially execute a query à-la...

```
SELECT * FROM page_view WHERE date > $from_date AND date < $to_date
```

... and store the result. This probably works better in a cron job.

The next time you need to display the information, you can just fetch the stored result and display it without re-computation. There are a variety of storage methods you can use: a MySQL table (e.g.: `page_view_compiled`), memcached, etc.